# AHK: convert ClipboardAll to string (without calling Clipboard instead)

Tags: autohotkey, clipboard

In an AHK script, I want to convert data I read from the clipboard earlier via ClipboardAll into a string I can manipulate, but StrGet() very oddly cannot do that.

```
!2:: clipget()
clipget()
    {
    clip := ClipboardAll
    MsgBox % clip
    MsgBox % NumGet(clip)
    MsgBox % StrGet(clip)
    Return
    }
```

Firts MsgBox returns empty, because clip is not a string, as expected.

Second returns a numerical representation of the bit data, as expected.

The third returns nothing, not as expected.

I know I could just use clipstr = Clipboard in the first place to have it converted in the first place, but then I would have to read the clipboard twice as in:

```
clip := ClipboardAll
clipstr := Clipboard
```

to get both string data and bit data, but that looks uncool and takes longer if the data on the cliboard is large.

A dumb but functional way way could also be

```
Clipboard := clip
Sleep 500
clipstr := Clipboard
```

needless to say is not what I am looking for.

So, **is there any way to get a string from ClipboardAll bit data with something like**

```
clip := ClipboardAll
clipstr := MagicalFunction(clip)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will help. But the clipboard is not the piece of string that is currently copied. The clipboard is a place where your computer holds your copied stuff, its a place where you can find your previous copied stuff.

A code I found in ahk's Clipboard doc is this

```
Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
{
    MsgBox, %A_LoopField% is your current copied first line..
}
```

I'm not very familiar with ahk's variable system but I think this should give a string output from %A_LoopField%

Answer (score 0):

1. in AHK script: Save ClipBoardAll to File.
2. in external text editor: Write to the BEGINING of File some text eg. "rrr" (or you can do it by "copy +" in command line bat file)
3. in AHK script: Read File to variable.